# Add link to another Action in AddModelError

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an error and I would like to add a link to it

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "You must have a confirmed email to log in.");
```

What I want to do is add a link to the SendEmailConfirmationMail action so I can resend it to them, in the event it was lost.

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmailConfirmationMail(string email, string returnUrl = null)
    {
  // Stuff removed
    }
```

What I have tried

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, 
                         $"You must have a confirmed email to log in. Click to resend conformation email <a href=account/SendEmailConfirmationMail?Email={model.Email}&returnUrl={returnUrl}> resend</a>");
```

and

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"<a href=\"{Url.Action("SendEmailConfirmationMail", "Account", new { Email = model.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl })}\">Click me</a>");
```

This doesnt work very well.

[image]

I am open to other ideas if I am doing this wrong.  I am still learning asp.net mvc.

From the view how its shown

```
 @if (error != null)
            {
                <strong>
                    <em> : @Html.Raw(error)</em>
                </strong>
            }
```

Update:

When i inspect the page.  It looks like the html is getting replaced.

```
<li>&lt;a href="/Account/SendEmailConfirmationMail?Email=lilaw@eg.dk"&gt;Click me&lt;/a&gt;</li>
```

Comment: In your view you might need to call @html.raw(errorMsg)

Comment: Are you in control of the view that displays the error, if yes show how do you render it?

Comment: @Zabavsky yes.  <em> : @Html.Raw(error)</em>   I added it to the question for you.

Comment: Would the downvoter please comment on the reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are in control of the view which displays the error, it would be better to format the error in the view itself since it's representation logic.

Add the model error in controller:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("EmailNotConfirmedError", string.Empty); // You can specify the error message or ignore it
```

Check for this specific error in the view:

```
<div>
    @if (ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey("EmailNotConfirmedError"))
    {
        <em>You must have a confirmed email to log in. Click to resend conformation email @Html.ActionLink("resend", "SendEmailConfirmationMail", "Account")</em>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `error` is an Html encoded string, you need to use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` to decode it first

```
<em> : @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(error))</em>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather use `@Url.Action()` method to get the URL

You can use it like this:

```
@Url.Action("MethodName","ControllerName",new{param1 = param1value});
```

**UPDATE**
To get your URL use this code:

```
var url = Url.Action("Account","SendEmailConfirmationMail",new{Email=model.Email,returnUrl = returnUrl;

ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, 
    $"You must have a confirmed email to log in. Click to resend conformation email {url})");
```

Comment: not exactly sure how you meant to add that but this doesnt work either  ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, @Url.Action("SendEmailConfirmationMail", "Account", new { Email = model.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl }));

Comment: That code will return an URL. How well do you know MVC?

Comment: Its not a url that the user can click on. Its just text.   I have been using C# for years, MVC three months.

Comment: See my UPDATE for you solution

Comment: The link appears correct but it looks like the html is getting replaced. <li>&lt;a href="/Account/SendEmailConfirmationMail?Email=lil@egadfdaf.dk"&gt;Click me&lt;/a&gt;</li>

Comment: You can add your html before the link: $"<li><a href='{url }'</a> CLICK ME </li>"

Comment: Yeah i did that its parsing it $"<a href=\"{Url.Action("SendEmailConfirmationMail", "Account", new { Email = model.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl })}\">Click me</a>"